# vba error 1004 method intersect of object _global failed

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

### UPDATE (question reworded)

I have 2 different Private Sub (in ThisWorkbook). Each is working fine "alone".
However, when they are both activated, I get the `vba error 1004 method intersect of object _global failed` error popping up if I click on any cell targeted in PS#2 (C20:C200).

The highlighted line of code when clicking on "debug" is in PS#1:

```
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("RSTcabFINISHING")) Is Nothing Then
```

What should I do to make both subs work together?

#### PRIVATE SUB #1

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
'Initialize cabinet finishing board
If testrange("RSTcabFINISHING") Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("RSTcabFINISHING")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Resize(, 3).ClearContents
    End If
End If

If testrange("RSTcabMATERIAL") Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("RSTcabMATERIAL")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Resize(, 3).ClearContents
    End If
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

#### PRIVATE SUB #2

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
'AUTO COMPLETE - initialize the script (to 0) each time a cell is selected in col "C")
If Selection.Count = 1 Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C20:C200")) Is Nothing Then
         Worksheets("HARD").Range("AUTOCOMPhardwareVBASCRIPT").Value = 0
         Worksheets("ACC-ST").Range("AUTOCOMPaccessoriesSTVBASCRIPT").Value = 0
         Worksheets("ACC-SP").Range("AUTOCOMPaccessoriesSPVBASCRIPT").Value = 0
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

#### Important point:

- I have a function "testrange" that is testing if the target range exists on the ActiveSheet (placed into a module), no problem there...
- I don't want to define a sheet name in PS#1 cause this sheet potentially needs to be duplicate.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Great detail in this post, but it may be too much. Please edit it and remove text that is not directly relevant to the issue. If a question has information that is not part of the issue, it can make it difficult to follow. This may be why you have not received a response. Please do some debugging and tell us where the error is coming from. **Then ask a specific question.** If you need help, read [ask] in the [help].

Comment: On what line in which macro does the error occur?

Comment: What do you mean by a blocking issue? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I just reworded the question to make it clearer (tell me otherwise). thx all!

Comment: Hi @CharlieRB, was wondering what to do. My post as been tagged "on hold" not being clear enough.
I edit it yesterday, and now it's closed. Do I repost it as it?

Answer (score 0):

In your statement `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C20:C200")) Is Nothing Then`
explicitly specify on which sheet where Range("C20:C200") resides. 

 Example: 
`If Not Intersect(Target, YourSheetHere.Range("C20:C200")) Is Nothing Then`